# Trying to draw a line with SVGPath in FXML

Tags: java, svg, javafx, fxml

So I'm trying to learn how to use svg in FXML and the first thing I want to do is to draw a simple line and then work my way up to other shapes. From what I've gathered online, all I have to do is give it a moveTo point and then a line point. If that's the case, then what am I missing?

```
<Button prefHeight="30" prefWidth="200" >
    <shape>
        <javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath content="M100,100 L150,150" /> 
    </shape>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sample Solution*

[image: svg path]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="86.0" prefWidth="99.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <SVGPath content="M40,60 L20,20" layoutX="18.0" layoutY="2.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeWidth="3.0" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

*Background*

You can refer to this [tutorial on svg paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) for background information (note JavaFX only processes path strings not full svg XML documents).

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you explain why it wasn't working for me?

Comment: Your original code wasn't trying to draw a line at all, it was trying to apply a shape to a button and it did not set a width for the stroke, so the line shape had no dimensions.

Comment: So if wanted to make a rectangle using my code, I would have to set  the strokeWidth to some number and give it more dimensions?

Comment: I tried to draw a rectangle but all I got was a very obscured figure with this path M 40 60 L 100 0 L 100 50 L 50 100 L 100 0 z

Comment: A path for a rectangle is in the tutorial that I linked (`M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10`).  Please read linked tutorials before asking additional questions.  Additionally, a rectangle requires a fill, not just a stroke (if you want a filled rectangle rather than just the outline of a rectangle).  If you search on the web you should be able to find vector drawing tools which can generate svg path strings for you based on a GUI drawing toolset (perhaps inkscape or the gimp, I'm not sure on exact tools).

Comment: I followed your instructions and used a vector drawing program to draw the shape that I wanted. I downloaded the svg file but now I have no idea what data I need to copy from inside the file in order to recreate the image that I drew in the program.

Comment: Please ask a new question for how to import your svg into your FXML, it is very hard to make good questions and answers in comments.